# How to delete an item into an array with a button

Tags: php, arrays

I have a code with an array that saves what i need each time I press a button, so these items saved into an array I showed later with a erase buttons, but I don't know how to delete it, so there is the part of the code that shows what I meant:

```
echo "<table border=1>";
    echo "<tr class='tabPreciosTitles'>";
      echo "<td>Nom Activitat</td>
            <td>Nom Tipus Activitat</td>
            <td>Tipus Tarifa</td>
            <td>Temps/km</td>
            <td>Preu</td>";
    echo "</tr>";
for ($x=0;$x<count($savedArray[4]);$x++){
  echo "<tr>";
  echo "  <td>".$savedArray[0][$x]."</td>";
  echo "  <td>".$savedArray[1][$x]."</td>";
  echo "  <td>".$savedArray[2][$x]."</td>";
  echo "  <td>".$savedArray[3][$x]."</td>";
  echo "  <td>".$savedArray[4][$x]."</td>";
  echo "  <td><input type='submit' onclick='eliminar(".$savedArray[0][$x].",".$savedArray[1][$x].",".$savedArray[2][$x].",".$savedArray[3][$x].",".$savedArray[4][$x].")' class='carritoElim' value='elim'></td>";
  echo "</tr>";
}
```

a pic with all the forms:

[image]

the other pic that shows the items on the array:

[image]

Anyone knows how to delete the selected row that references the item on the array with the delete button? Thanks

Comment: The array is gone when the page is sent to the browser. PHP variables don't persist after the script ends, except for session variables.

Comment: If you just want to delete the array in the browser, you have to use Javascript.

Answer (score 0):

In the client side, the following code works.

```
for ($x=0;$x<count($savedArray[4]);$x++){
  echo '<tr id="line' . $x . '">';
  echo "  <td>".$savedArray[0][$x]."</td>";
  echo "  <td>".$savedArray[1][$x]."</td>";
  echo "  <td>".$savedArray[2][$x]."</td>";
  echo "  <td>".$savedArray[3][$x]."</td>";
  echo "  <td>".$savedArray[4][$x]."</td>";
  echo "  <td><input type='submit' onclick='eliminar('line" . $x . "')' class='carritoElim' value='elim'></td>";
 echo "</tr>";
}

function eliminar($id) {
  var elem = document.getElementById($id);
  elem.parentNode.removeChild(elem);
}
```

However, if you want to delete column in the server side also, the ajax codes should be added.

Comment: so, that removes the row with the selected id right? and it removes too the item on the array?

Answer (score 0):

php is a server side language, what meant once your response is sent out to the client(browser), under most case all your "saved" data/variables will be lost.

I am not a fan of what your language of choice for this task but here is a way to work around.

The trick is to scan the whole table of data when the user clicked the eliminate button, then send all the data back to the sever and recreate the array with the selected row taken out. Then print the whole array back to html format and send it to user again.

The critical part to of this method is that you NEED to print everything you wish to retain in every response, so that you could scan them all back in to your server side program.

I've some sample code for your reference, but I didn't pay much attention when I wrote them so expect bugs and incorrect syntax, this is just for pure demostration purpose to show you the idea.

the sample code to print the table you've shown:

```
echo "<form action='".$_PHP_SELF."' method='post'>";
echo "<input type='hidden' name='type' value='yourarrayname'/>";
echo "<table border=1>";
echo "<tr class='tabPreciosTitles'>";
  echo "<td>Nom Activitat</td>
        <td>Nom Tipus Activitat</td>
        <td>Tipus Tarifa</td>
        <td>Temps/km</td>
        <td>Preu</td>";
echo "</tr>";
for ($x=0;$x<count($savedArray[4]);$x++){
  if(strcasecmp($savedArray[0][$x],"-999")!=0){
  echo "<tr>";
  echo "<td><input type='text' name='0_".$x."' value='".$savedArray[0][$x]."'/></td>";
  echo "<td><input type='text' name='1_".$x."' value='".$savedArray[1][$x]."'/></td>";
  echo "<td><input type='text' name='2_".$x."' value='".$savedArray[2][$x]."'/></td>";
  echo "<td><input type='text' name='3_".$x."' value='".$savedArray[3][$x]."'/></td>";
  echo "<td><input type='text' name='4_".$x."' value='".$savedArray[4][$x]."'/></td>";
  echo "<td><button name='elim' value='e".$x."' type='submit'>elim</button></td>";
  echo "</tr>";
  }
}
echo "</table>";
echo "</form>";
```

and here's the sample code to handle the incoming data, put this after you created the array but before the printing code:

```
if($_POST!=null){       
    if(strcasecmp($_POST['type'],"yourarrayname")==0){
        for ($x=0;$x<count($savedArray[4]);$x++){
            if(strcasecmp($_POST['elim'],"e".$x)!=0){
                $savedArray[0][$x] = $_POST['0_'.$x];
                $savedArray[1][$x] = $_POST['1_'.$x];
                $savedArray[2][$x] = $_POST['2_'.$x];
                $savedArray[3][$x] = $_POST['3_'.$x];
                $savedArray[4][$x] = $_POST['4_'.$x];
            }
            if(strcasecmp($_POST['elim'],"e".$x)==0){
                $savedArray[0][$x] = "-999";
                $savedArray[1][$x] = "-999";
                $savedArray[2][$x] = "-999";
                $savedArray[3][$x] = "-999";
                $savedArray[4][$x] = "-999";
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: No, that's so simple, i need something to delete the line and the item inside the array too :/

Comment: there are lots of ways to do it, but I think this the easiest method for new programmer to understand with pure php.